# Downloading files to newly created directories in C#

Tags: c#

I am creating directories on the fly and I would like to download files to the newly created directory:

```
// The code to create the directory based on revision number and original name
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\bob\Desktop\Hello\Files\" + "v" + fileInfo.RevisionNumber + "_" + fileInfo.OriginalName);

// This method downloads files and takes 4 parameters. 
// The only one that really matters is the second one, targetFolder, 
// which is a String value. Any idea on how I can download the files 
// to the newly created directory (above) using the method below?
ecm.RetrieveFile(fileInfo.ID, targetFolder, recreateDirectoryStructureFlag, overwriteWithoutPromptFlag);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreateDirectory` returns a `DirectoryInfo` object.  If you store that returned object, you can then pass `newDirectory.FullPath` to the download function.

Answer (score 4):

```
var targetFolder = @"C:\Users\bob\Desktop\Hello\Files\" + "v" + fileInfo.RevisionNumber + "_" + fileInfo.OriginalName;
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetFolder);
ecm.RetrieveFile(fileInfo.ID, targetFolder, recreateDirectoryStructureFlag, overwriteWithoutPromptFlag);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the same string that you passed to `CreateDirectory`.
It may be useful to put the string in a separate variable and pass the variable to both functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
string targetFolder= System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\bob\Desktop\Hello\Files\" + "v" + fileInfo.RevisionNumber + "_" + fileInfo.OriginalName).FullName;

ecm.RetrieveFile(fileInfo.ID, targetFolder, recreateDirectoryStructureFlag, overwriteWithoutPromptFlag);
```

Answer (score 0):

I learned that the DirectoryInfo object has a FullName method that returns the full path. I used this method to get the path.

Thanks all for the help.